# POST CSV to server using python

Tags: python, api, post

I an trying to Post CSV using python request. I am using the following code but getting this error:

`{"code":400,"message":"Invalid input parameters","status":"error"}`

Here is my code:

```py
import requests
import json

api_url = "https://anlyticstts.com//api/insights/v1/reports"

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-access-key': 'e13168e9f1504d63455'
}

data = {
 "search_term_ids": [60, 61],
 "product_list_ids": [120],
 "start_date": "20180801",
 "end_date": "20180805",   
 "columns": {
 "product": ["crawl_date", "product_name"],
 "status": ["no_longer_available"],
 "ranking": ["search_rank"],
 "pricing": ["price"]},
 "page_one_only": True, "format": "csv"
}
r = requests.post(url=api_url, data=data, headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: Shouldn't your api url be api_url = "https://anlyticstts.com/api/insights/v1/reports" instead of api_url = "https://anlyticstts.com//api/insights/v1/reports"

Comment: still getting the same error?

Comment: I think you should try requests.post(api_url, data=data, headers=headers) instead of requests.post(url=api_url, data=data, headers=headers)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sample code
import json

`r = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)`

instead of

`r = requests.post(url=api_url, data=data, headers=headers)`

Comment: Please try with json.dumps your data. If it does not work then can you check your data while sending is proper json data